# Need to combine 2 cron lines to 1 if possible

Tags: unix, cron, aix

I need to create a cron entry that will kick off a command at both 11:30AM and 4:00PM monday through friday. Is there anyway to do this in one entry or will I need to use two?

This would be great for anyone who has specific times to run their job that don't fall on the same minute of the hours it runs.

Currently I can only figure a two line systems as follows, is this the only way?

`# 30 11 * * 1-5 /cmd1`

`# 00 16 * * 1-5 /cmd1`

Comment: It is not possible to combine it on just one line.

Comment: Can you post this as an aswer so that I can accept it and close the question. Your advice was quite useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to combine it on just one line.

What you suggest to do:

```
30 11,16 * * 1-5 /cmd1
```

would execute even at 16.30.

Then, the only way is splitting in two pieces as you already have:

```
30 11 * * 1-5 /cmd1
00 16 * * 1-5 /cmd1
```

Comment: Again this is what I expected but the information verified allows me to review with my supervisor that the solution provided is the best practice without altering times.

Comment: I hope not being involved in trials if we find out a better way to do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this :

```
30 11,16 * * 1-5 /cmd1
```

if you accept to change the time of the second command to 16:30.

Comment: Correct I was just verifying that I could not do it. my Supervisor was asking me about all the entries and I couldnt really verify no there is no way with my experience so I was asking the community with more experience. Thank you for your replies.